# Google Apps Script: How to compile all messages into one popup at the end of the operation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script I'm running a macro that triggers several functions. Each function may result in a message for the user. Rather than have the user individually click through each message from each function, is it possible to compile all of them into one popup at the end?

For simplicity, let's say there's `mainFunction` that triggers `functionA` and then `functionB` to process through two different tables. At the end of running `functionA` it will have either processed through its table or prepared the message `No new data in Table A`. Same with `functionB` for Table B.

However, if there's no new data in either, it would be better to save this as one popup at the end that says `No new data in Table A. No new data in Table B.`

The identifier for recognizing there's no new data is when `finalarray.length = 0`.

What's an efficient way to set this up?

```
function mainFunction (){

functionA();
functionB();
}

function functionA () {

if (finalarray.length = 0) {

}
}

function functionB () {

if (finalarray.length = 0) {

}
}
```

Comment: What does the keyword `return` do?

Comment: I understand the basics of `return`, and recognize I can pull that value in from another function. Where I am getting stuck is how to combine returns from multiple functions together in the same message box.

Comment: it's basic string concatenation: `Browser.msgBox(functionA()+functionB())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `return` to return data from a function
- Concat returned strings together using `+`

```js
function main(){
  alert(a()+b()+c());
}

function a(){
  return "Hello";
}

function b(){
  return "World";
}
const c = ()=>"!!!"
main()
```

Comment: Yes okay got it. Is there any way to accomodate for the fact that if you insert a space between them with `a()+' '+b()` it will look fine if there's a message from both. But if there's not a message from `a()` there will be an unnecessary space in front of `b()`?

Comment: I suppose you could add a space after Hello with `"Hello "` but just wondering if there's syntax in the concat to handle it.

Comment: Not really. You would need a `if...else`

Answer (score 0):

```
function (mainFunction){
  var msg=functionA();
  msg+=mfunctionB();
  Browser.msgBox(msg)
}

function (functionA) {
  var msg='No new data in A';
  if (finalarray.length = 0) {
    msg='Final Array A length is ' + finalarray.length;
  }

  return msg;
}

function (functionB) {
  var msg='No new data in B';
  if (finalarray.length = 0) {
    msg='Final Array B length is ' + finalarray.length;
  }
  return msg;
}
```

Comment: When I try to run this it tells me **SyntaxError: Unexpected token +=** which is in regards to the `var msg+=mfunctionB();` line. Also note I originally misplaced the function names to be inside the parentheses. I have edited the syntax accordingly.

Comment: I made a small change. But I didn’t mean for this to be a plug and play solution.  You may have think a little on your own